# Xamarin.Forms NavigationPage and screen rotation

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, screen-rotation

I started Xamarin.Forms and it is great with MVVM pattern.

As main page I use NavigationPage and navigate with PushAsync and PopAsync brteen different pages. This works great if the phone stays in the same orientation. If I rotate screen, Xamarin shows always the first page after rotation.

How can I prevent this? I want to support the screen rotation and don't loose the navigation stack after rotation.

Comment: Could you provide your sample, because navigation works properly on my side after rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible when running Android. Make sure that your MainActivity class has the `ConfigurationChanges` attributes. Here is an example:

```
[Activity(Label = "MYProject.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```